# PHP & IIS 6 Encoding problem

Tags: iis, php, encoding

The server is running Windows 2003 with IIS 6.0.3790.1830 x86 (iis.dll).
My database server is Microsoft SQL Server 2000. My PHP version is 5.3.

The **original** application is hosted on `appserv1` and it's database is on `dbserv1`. It's working fine, everything is tuned up, running great.

It was needed to place the same application (different modules) on another server, for other uses, so I copied the database on `dbserv2`, configured `appserv2` to host the application, so I achieved 2 almost identical copies. Both `dbserv1` and `dbserv2` use the same encoding, both `appserv1` and `appserv2` are on IIS6 with the same PHP configurations. I also tried my best to have the same settings in the IIS. I also made sure that I pass the encoding information both in the HTTP headers and in the meta tags with http-equiv. Both applications use utf-8.

**The Problem** is that the copy of the application doesn't display the non-ASCII characters normally in the browser, even if the browser detects correctly the UTF-8 encoding of the page. First I thought it was a database issue, given the fact that MSSQL 2000 doesn't support UTF-8, and instead it uses UCS-2, but when I redirected the application on `appserv2` to work with the database on `dbserv1`, it had the same encoding problems.

This is why I am asking in what way I can make it work.

thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys, I figured it out (by trying everything I could).
The problem was in the server's regional settings, the codepage to use for non-unicode programs (damn, I thought that the server operates with byte-streams, and they are transformed to characters client-side, but it seems there's more to it).